# how can I add jar dependencies to generated aar

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, jar, aar

First i will explain my project structure

```
Test Application
|
| - Library Module
|   |
|   | - Core Library Module
|       | Module 1
|       |- Jar dependency 1
|       |
|       | Module 2
|       |- Jar dependency 2
```

I have a test application that _I use to test a library module which is use to generate an aar file, which is distributed to other apps.

The library module has a dependency on another module, which contains some core functionality for my library and other libraries.

The problem is that the core library has 2 dependencies, 2 jar files. those are added to the project as modules that only contain that jar.

Now, when I generate the aar file for the library module those jar files are not added to the aar. I do not want to add those jars directly to client apps, so my only solution is to find a way to add them to the aar file.

I añready tried to add them using this https://github.com/adwiv/android-fat-aar, with no luck because that is used to add regular modules to an aar but not just a jar file.

Is there any way to add those jars to the aar? the aar is generated in jenkins and deployed into artifactory.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I could'nt find a direct way of doing this, but i will explain my work around in case someone else have the same problem, and maybe this will work for you. I won't set this answer as the correct one because maybe someone else can give us a better one.

Because i could'nt add the jars files in a direct way, I created a gradle tak that copies all files that are inside the jars i wanted to add into de the classes directory before gradle join them into the class.jar file that is inside the .aar file.

this is the gradle task

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
if (task.name == 'bundleRelease') {
    task.dependsOn embedJavaJarsCustom
}
}

task embedJavaJarsCustom << {

def finalPath = '/Users/jenkins/workspace/MyProject/MyLibrary/libs'
    // Collect list of all jar files
    FileTree jars = fileTree(dir: finalPath, include: ['*.jar'])

    println "Embedding jars : " + jars

    // Explode all jar files to classes so that they can be proguarded
    jars.visit {
        FileVisitDetails element ->
            println element.getName()
            if (element.getName().equals('my.jar')
                    || element.getName().equals('my2.jar') ) {
                    copy {

                        from(zipTree(element.file))
                        into("${getProject().getBuildDir()}/intermediates/classes/release/")
                    }
            }

    }
}
```